# Should BFF or GraphQL be before or After the API Gateway?

Tags: graphql, microservices, api-gateway

In the microservices architecture, the BFF/GraphQL for the transformation of the response be before or after the API gateway?

So should it be Client -> GraphQL -> API Gateway -> Service

OR should it be Client -> API Gateway -> GraphQL -> Service

Assuming that API Gateway and Service and GraphQL are hosted on the same cloud.

Comment: That always depends on what your API Gateway does. You can even have a GraphQL as API Gateway. But anyway I would say the second option is the more used.